# Why are the styles of my scss module being applied to the wrong component?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm building a website with gatsby and I have set up the gatsby scss plugin. Everything seemed to be working fine until I realized my styles from `home.module.scss` were also being applied to my navigation component that only imports `navbar.module.scss`.

I have a style for my buttons in each of these modules that looks like this...

```
button {
  // different styles in the different modules
}
```

Both of these modules import a global scss file at the top like this...
`@import '../styles/global.scss';`

The react components only import their respective modules. In my main index component I import global styles like this `import './global.scss'`

Am I misunderstanding how scss modules work in React or is this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding
In react importing SCSS or CSS in any component will be global.
So it will affect all other components as similar to the component where you imported the SCSS file.

use different class names

Comment: Ok thanks. That makes CSS modules in React seem pretty pointless then